# How to multiply the values of two values in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL6f2tow/47/)

I have used the `item` and `sum` to get the values

i.e.,

The value of all `item 1` will be added in the `sum_1`,  `item 2` to `sum_2` and it keeps on.

But i want to multiply the `item 1` and  `multiply 1` and show it in the `sum_1` and vice versa for all.

How can i do this

```
var totalElement = $('.total');

$('.item').each(function () {

    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice(itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1);

    var sumElement = $(".sum_" + itemNumber);
    var sum = (sumElement.val() == "") ? 0 : parseInt(sumElement.val());
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    sumElement.val(sum);

    calculateTotal();
});

$(document).on("change", ".item", function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice(itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1);
    $('.' + itemNumber).each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $(".sum_" + itemNumber).val(sum);

    calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[class^=sum_]').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    totalElement.val(total);
}
```

Comment: I've opened the question yo see this image )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Values :

<input type="text" class="item 1" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="2" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="3" />
<input type="text" class="item 2" value="4" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="6" />
<input type="text" class="item 3" value="7" />
<Hr>
<br>
Multiplier :
<input type="text" class="multiply_1" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="multiply_2" value="6" />
<input type="text" class="multiply_3" value="7" />
<Hr>
    <br>
        Result :


<input type="text" class="sum_1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="sum_2" value="" />
<input type="text" class="sum_3" value="" />
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" class="total" value="" />
<script>
var totalElement = $('.total');

$('.item').each(function () {

    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice(itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1);

    var sumElement = $(".sum_" + itemNumber);
    var sum = (sumElement.val() == "") ? 0 : parseInt(sumElement.val());
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    sumElement.val(sum);

    calculateTotal();
});

$(document).on("change", ".item", function () {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemNumber = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    itemNumber.splice(itemNumber.indexOf("item"), 1);
    $('.' + itemNumber).each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    var multiple=$(".multiply_"+ itemNumber).val();

    var funalsum=parseInt(multiple)*parseInt(sum);
    $(".sum_" + itemNumber).val(funalsum);

    calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('[class^=sum_]').each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    totalElement.val(total);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/wz16yq2v/2/
```

As you told you want to multiply the "item 1" and  "multiply 1" means the condition will be like this.
sum = item 1 * multiply 1 * multiply 1.....(if multiply 1 exist)